# Get CPU core voltage values on linux server

Tags: linux

I'm on a RedHat 5 server, with lm-sensors 3.3.4 installed,

and I executed sensors-detect and then run "sensors", then it just output:

No sensors found!

Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need.

Try sensors-detect to find out which these are.

How could I get cpu core voltage values from this tool? Do I have to install some drivers or something?
If yes, how do I know what drivers I need to download?
dmidecode shows that: Product Name: ProLiant SL390s G7

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [superuser](http://superuser.com/) is a better place for this question. However you may try `sensors-detect`.

Comment: Sorry for posting at wrong place, I run sensors-detect before I run the command "sensors", and then I got the message "No sensors found!.."

Comment: Is it a VPS? (virtual servers probably don't have meaningful voltage sensors).

Comment: No it's not a virtual server

Answer (score 4):

`sudo dmidecode --type processor | grep Voltage`

Comment: Does this shows current cpu voltage value or just the cpu voltage spec.?

Comment: @user1815783 Just the cpu voltage spec.